# How to apply a style on links with querystrings

Tags: html, css

So basically if you want an indicator on the link of the page you are currently on you just apply a style on the page for example:

```
<li><a href="home.aspx" class="active">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about.aspx">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.aspx">CONTACT</a></li>
```

It will apply whatever style is on the class `active` when you are in the `home.aspx` page...

Now I have something similar but this time, instead of directing to another page, the links will just redirect on the same page but filtered with querystrings...

I have:

```
<li><a href="projects.aspx?id=PROJECT1">PROJECT 1</a></li>
<li><a href="projects.aspx?id=PROJECT2">PROJECT 2</a></li>
<li><a href="projects.aspx?id=PROJECT3">PROJECT 3</a></li>
```

What I would like to happen is I want to apply a css style when I click one of those links so that people know which project they are looking at.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, but there is no reason to do this with JQuery/JS unless you are not reloading the page (appears you are). Just use `Request.QueryString("id");` and depending on the value, output your desired CSS style.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a little jquery to add the .`active` class to selected element.

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($){
  var url = window.location.href;
  // give the li or a tag a class
     $('.element-class-name a[href="'+ url +'"]').addClass('active');

     $('.element-class-name a').filter(function() {

     return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try caching selector `$("a[href^=projects]")` as variable , attach `click` event to cached selector , utilize `.each()` to iterate all elements in collection , set `className` to `"active"` if  `this` current element `===` `event.target`

```
var a = $("a[href^=projects]");
a.click(function(e) {
  a.each(function() {
    this.className = this === e.target ? "active" : ""
  })
})
```

```js
var a = $("a[href^=projects]");
a.click(function(e) {
  // Note, `e.preventDefault()` included for stacksnippets
  e.preventDefault();
  a.each(function() {
    this.className = this === e.target ? "active" : ""
  })
})
```

```css
a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="projects.aspx?id=PROJECT1">PROJECT 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="projects.aspx?id=PROJECT2">PROJECT 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="projects.aspx?id=PROJECT3">PROJECT 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing something like the following works also:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.links li .link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Where link is the class I gave the actual link within a list called links.

The example is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyJgBQ